SDK for authorised login with Google Login support
enter image description here
I want to implement a feature which is providing a login sdk to let other app login by my app. the page like this telegram screenshot.
Firstly I want to use webview to implement this feature, access to my authorisation page, and use a scheme jump return to my app after authorisation.
My app support google login, but when I use webview to implement this feature, google login then fails to load the google login sdk properly.
Can anyone tell me what can be done with a feature like this?
